# locale issue on newly CentOS install

Tags: centos, systemd, locale

I made several CentOS 7 install lately using the NetInstall CD and all is going well, installation finishes, I can access the server. However when I try to connect to the server using ssh afterwards, I get :

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

indeed typing "locale" I get:

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Set up is:

```
# cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG="en_US.utf8"
[root@moria ~]# localectl list-locales | grep en_US
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
```

So nothing fancy, it's a fresh out of the box updated CentOS.

Trying to set it I get :

```
# localectl set-locale LC_TYPE=en_US.utf8
Failed to issue method call: Invalid Locale data.
```

So my question:
What am I missing? How to set this up correctly. Many thanks!

Comment: Are you SSH'ing in via a mac by any chance? By default it'll carry over currently set environment variables, including any that are invalid on the box you're connecting to. In iTerm, there's a checkbox in the profile->Terminal Tab to not do this. 

otherwise, you could just export the environment variable once you log in, but that's not really a permanent fix... `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: nope, not only the Mac, from other linux box too running ubuntu :(

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem.
The solution was to install the expected language package :

```
yum install glibc-langpack-en.x86_64
```

Note: it is on CentOS 8, but I guess the solution would be similar on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Your LC_CTYPE variable appears to be defined incorrectly. It should be:

```
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

instead of

```
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

As RobotJohnny stated, it may have something to do with your SSH client.

Comment: well it should be even en_US.utf8 without the dash but it is set like this and I cannot change it with localectl either ... I can always export variables but sounds more like a hack than anything else